# Mounting device from degraded RAID 1

Tags: linux, raid, mdadm

I am trying to mount device form raid 1 (created on other device), because I need to copy data from this disk. When I am trying to assemble new array i get a message:

```
foo@bar# mdadm -A -R -v /dev/md23 /dev/sdb3
mdadm: looking for devices for /dev/md23
mdadm: /dev/sdb3 is identified as a member of /dev/md23, slot 32769.
mdadm: No suitable drives found for /dev/md23
```

Here is my examine:

```
foo@bar# mdadm -E /dev/sdb3
/dev/sdb3:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : 4bd4d90c:5ca25815:87c31c08:a6288e71
           Name : DiskStation:2
  Creation Time : Tue Jun 26 10:13:40 2012
     Raid Level : raid1
   Raid Devices : 2

 Avail Dev Size : 5851088833 (2790.02 GiB 2995.76 GB)
     Array Size : 2925544256 (2790.02 GiB 2995.76 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 5851088512 (2790.02 GiB 2995.76 GB)
    Data Offset : 2048 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 6f42964f:0fbc4d3b:63179370:796cf9e3

    Update Time : Thu Dec 25 21:14:04 2014
       Checksum : 1d6a7257 - correct
         Events : 10811864


   Device Role : Active device 32769
   Array State : .. ('A' == active, '.' == missing)
```

How to mount disk from raid 1 array to copy data from it?

EDIT:

When I try to mount md23 (it took few minutes to response):

```
foo@bar# mount -o ro /dev/md23 /media/syno-1/
mount: /dev/md23: can't read superblock
```

Comment: Did the old `md` device contain a single file system, or was it LVM'ed inside?

Comment: what happen if you try to mount /dev/md23?

Comment: @MadHatter It contain a single fs, ext4.

Comment: @kocur then I think thst has the right answer, below.

Comment: @MadHatter
I've added Edit.

Comment: @c4f4t0r It can't read superblock. I've added edit with output.

Comment: dumpe2fs /dev/md23 and blkid?

Comment: At the momnent, I see no evidence that this partition contains a single FS, as you say it does.  Why do you think this is the case?  Can we see any output from the old system, when this was part of the RAID, to confirm it?  `cat /proc/mdstat` on the new system might be useful, too.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried to simply mount the disk? As raid1 is mirror, linux can mount the degraded disk as single disc, iirc.

you should mount readonly, to avoid problems:

```
mount -o ro /dev/sdb3 /mnt
```

Comment: node01:~ # mount /dev/xvde /mnt
mount: unknown filesystem type 'linux_raid_member'

Comment: must have been very old md tools in my mind then. anyway, the AR combo used by the op should have done the job.  Maybe dd to file and then switch the fstype or give a fstype explicitely? Just a guess...